# Get filename without extension after choose file with prompt

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm trying to write a small gpx file conversion script. The conversion part is done but I can't fix the naming of the converted file. I want the filename of the converted file like this:

```
originalfilename.2.gpx
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
-- begin script
-- For converting from one format to another. Preset to convert from GPX to KML. Tailor as needed. Read the documentation for your version

--Based on the script by Robert Nixon, http://www.gpsbabel.org/os/OSX_oneclick.html


-- This is set up for gpsbabel installed using DarwinPorts. See <http://www.gpsbabel.org/osnotes.html> for details
-- This script is not being actively supported, but you may get some help from the gpsbabel discussion group: <http://www.gpsbabel.org/lists.html>
--start script

-- HINT a '~/' is your home folder and of course the double hyphen is a comment. Remove to make active.

-- setting path for gpsbabel. Reset as needed
--set gpsBabelLocation to "/opt/local/var/db/dports/software/gpsbabel/1.2.7_0/opt/local/bin/" -- DarwinPorts Default for Tiger, Feb. 2006
set gpsBabelLocation to "/Applications/GPSBabelFE.app/Contents/MacOS/" -- Normal MacGPSBabel location
--set gpsBabelLocation to ""

set inputTYPE to "gpx" -- set the input file type to whatever you want  
set outputTYPE to "gpx" --set the output file type to whatever you want
set strPath to POSIX file "/Users/someusername/downloads/" --set the default path for file input dialog

--set inputPATH to "~/Desktop/route.gpx" --set the path to where your input file is
-- comment out the following line if you want to use the line above



set inputPATHalias to (choose file with prompt "Select a GPX file to convert to " & outputTYPE & ":" default location strPath)

-- set inputPATH to quoted form of POSIX path of inputPATHalias  -- got error, but two step below works.

set inputfilename to (inputPATHalias as text)


set inputPATH to POSIX path of inputPATHalias




set inputPATH to quoted form of inputPATH -- needed to pass to shell script



--set outputPATH to "~/Desktop/yournewfile.wpt" --set the path to where your output file will be
set outputFileName to "converted." & inputTYPE & ".2." & outputTYPE
--set outputFileName to outputFileName & ".2." & outputTYPE


set outputFolderalias to choose folder with prompt "Select a folder for converted file:"
set outputPATH to fileCheckName(outputFolderalias, outputFileName)

-- See the Documentation for normal usage. http://www.gpsbabel.org/readme.html#d0e1388
-- Using the Position filter to correct a Garmin error. When the Garmin loses sight of the sattiletes, when it reconects, it puts in poitns with a lat-long equal to the last good point, but current time and elevation (mine has a barometer). Garmin: remove extraneous points recorded when out of range that have same lat and long as last good point (altitude is ignored in this filter). 
set filterSetting to "" -- use this one if you don't want any Position filtering. You can leave in uncommented and any below will override it.
-- set filterSetting to " -x position " -- Default, distance=0
-- set filterSetting to " -x position,distance=1f " -- 1 foot and leave one
-- set filterSetting to " -x position,distance=1m " -- 1 meter and leave one
-- set filterSetting to " -x position,all"  -- remove all duplicates
-- set filterSetting to " -x simplify,count=1000"
-- set filterSetting to " -x simplify,error=1k" -- doesnt' work, but then it's not in the manual
-- set filterSetting to ""

tell application "System Events"
    activate
    do shell script gpsBabelLocation & "gpsbabel " & filterSetting & "-i " & inputTYPE & " -f " & inputPATH & " -x transform,trk=rte " & " -o " & outputTYPE & " -F " & outputPATH
end tell

--Handlers. Only used once, but I've used them elsewhere
on fileCheckName(outputFolderalias, outputFileName)
    set outputFolder to POSIX path of outputFolderalias
    set outputPATHnoQuote to outputFolder & "/" & outputFileName -- may need to change this if the extension isn't the same as the outputType, The Desktop is a common location
    set outputPATH to quoted form of outputPATHnoQuote -- needed to pass to shell script
    
    --check if file already exist and if we want to overwrite it
    set outputFolderaliasText to outputFolderalias as text
    set outputPATHcolon to outputFolderaliasText & outputFileName
    tell application "Finder" -- trying to get handler to work
        if file outputPATHcolon exists then display dialog "The file " & outputFileName & " already exists. Do you want to overwrite it?"
    end tell
    return outputPATH
end fileCheckName







--end script
```

I'm unable to find Applescript code that translates the filename from a prompt into a variable.

Comment: Are you taking about something like `choose file name`?

Comment: Not in the sense that the user can choose a filename. The original filename should be extracted after the ‘choose file with prompt’ screen. In other words: after the user has selected a file the filename should be put into a variable.
After that one or more characters (or words) are added to the end of the original filename. That’s how we get to originalfilename.2.gpx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to not use the Finder.app at all for this task. Especially, checking file existence with the **Posix file** coercion inside the **tell block** is a big mistake. The Finder is also not needed to get the file **basename**. For this task, with the help of other experienced users, I developed a high-speed handler, provided here.

In general, I recommend using the Finder only when absolutely necessary, because it is often busy in the background with other time-consuming tasks.

```
set gpsBabelLocation to "/Applications/GPSBabelFE.app/Contents/MacOS/" -- Normal MacGPSBabel location

set inputType to "gpx" -- the input file type extension  
set outputType to "gpx" -- the output file type extension
set defaultPath to (path to downloads folder)
set inputPath to (choose file of type inputType with prompt "Select a " & inputType & " file to convert to " & outputType & ":" default location defaultPath) -- remove 'of type inputType' to select any file
set outputFileName to getBaseName(POSIX path of inputPath) & ".2." & outputType -- the converted name

set outputFolder to choose folder with prompt "Select a folder for the converted file:"
set outputPath to fileCheckName(outputFolder, outputFileName)

set filterSetting to ""
set inputPath to quoted form of (POSIX path of inputPath)
set command to gpsBabelLocation & "gpsbabel " & filterSetting & "-i " & inputType & " -f " & inputPath & " -x transform,trk=rte " & " -o " & outputType & " -F " & outputPath
log command
if gpsBabelLocation is not "" then
    do shell script command
    log result
end if


on getBaseName(posixPath)
    set {ATID, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, "/"}
    if (posixPath ends with "/") then
        set baseName to text item -2 of posixPath
    else
        set baseName to text item -1 of posixPath
    end if
    if (baseName contains ".") then
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "."
        set baseName to text 1 thru text item -2 of baseName
    end if
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ATID
    return baseName
end getBaseName


on fileCheckName(outputFolder, outputFileName) -- check if file exists
    try
        alias (outputFolder & outputFileName)
        display alert quoted form of outputFileName & " already exists. Do you want to replace it?" message "A file or folder with the same name already exists at " & quoted form of POSIX path of outputFolder & ". Replacing it will overwrite its current contents." buttons {"OK", "Cancel"}
        if button returned of the result is "Cancel" then error number -128 -- alert doesn't automatically cancel
    end try
    return quoted form of ((POSIX path of outputFolder) & outputFileName) -- quote for the shell script
end fileCheckName
```

Comment: Ah! Thanks Robert. That's a nice addition to an already perfect solution. And I can still follow/understand the code as an Applescript newbie. Even if the code of @red_menace is already doing the job fine I prefer your solution. Better performance although not really noticeable right now. It may become noticeable when I reuse the code for heavier tasks. Thank you so much for helping me out with this 

Answer (score 0):

**Finder** or **System Events** can be used to get file names, you just need to be a little careful when using the Finder, since it doesn't know that much about POSIX paths.  With the various quoting for the shell, you also need to manipulate the various name pieces *before* quoting.  Shortened and cleaned up a bit, your script would be something like:

```
--Based on the script by Robert Nixon, http://www.gpsbabel.org/os/OSX_oneclick.html

-- set path for gpsbabel as needed:
-- set gpsBabelLocation to "/opt/local/var/db/dports/software/gpsbabel/1.2.7_0/opt/local/bin/" -- DarwinPorts Default for Tiger, Feb. 2006
set gpsBabelLocation to "/Applications/GPSBabelFE.app/Contents/MacOS/" -- Normal MacGPSBabel location
-- set gpsBabelLocation to "" -- testing, etc

set inputType to "gpx" -- the input file type extension  
set outputType to "gpx" -- the output file type extension

set defaultPath to (path to downloads folder)
set inputPath to (choose file of type inputType with prompt "Select a " & inputType & " file to convert to " & outputType & ":" default location defaultPath) -- remove 'of type inputType' to select any file

tell application "Finder" to set {inputName, inputExt} to {name, name extension} of inputPath
if inputExt is not "" then set inputName to text 1 thru -((count inputExt) + 2) of inputName -- just the name part
set inputPath to quoted form of POSIX path of inputPath -- quote for the shell script
set outputFileName to inputName & ".2." & outputType -- the converted name

set outputFolder to choose folder with prompt "Select a folder for the converted file:"
set outputPath to fileCheckName(outputFolder, outputFileName)

-- See the Documentation for normal usage. http://www.gpsbabel.org/readme.html#d0e1388

set filterSetting to "" -- uncomment any below to override no position filtering
-- set filterSetting to " -x position " -- Default, distance=0
-- set filterSetting to " -x position,distance=1f " -- 1 foot and leave one
-- set filterSetting to " -x position,distance=1m " -- 1 meter and leave one
-- set filterSetting to " -x position,all"  -- remove all duplicates
-- set filterSetting to " -x simplify,count=1000"

set command to gpsBabelLocation & "gpsbabel " & filterSetting & "-i " & inputType & " -f " & inputPath & " -x transform,trk=rte " & " -o " & outputType & " -F " & outputPath
log command
if gpsBabelLocation is not "" then
   do shell script command
   log result
end if

on fileCheckName(outputFolder, outputFileName) -- check if file exists
   set outputPath to (POSIX path of outputFolder) & outputFileName
   tell application "Finder" to if (outputPath as POSIX file) exists then -- match the save alert
      display alert quoted form of outputFileName & " already exists. Do you want to replace it?" message "A file or folder with the same name already exists at " & quoted form of POSIX path of outputFolder & ". Replacing it will overwrite its current contents." buttons {"OK", "Cancel"}
      if button returned of the result is "Cancel" then error number -128 -- alert doesn't automatically cancel
   end if
   return quoted form of outputPath -- quote for the shell script
end fileCheckName
```

Comment: It's entirely possible I've missed something as I'm reading your code and writing this comment whilst sat on the toilet.  But as far as I can see, you've set `inputName` to the `name` property of the `inputPath`, which would include its extension, to which `".2."` is appended and assigned to `outputFileName`.  Wouldn't that end up creating a file name of the ilk _`"originalfilename.gpx.2.gpx"`_ ?

Comment: Thank you both CJK and red_menace for replying. Been looking at it for days  Yes, I want to remove the original extension. The end result should look like this; `originalfilename.2.gpx`.

Comment: @johansson - the original script had the inputType extension for the default converted name, so it was included.  I've edited to remove the input extension.

Comment: @red_menace Yes that did the trick. Nice to now that Applescript has a thru function to perform text trimming tasks. I will remember this example. For now I prefer the solution that Robert-Kniazidis provided.

Comment: @johansson - No problem, the correct answer is what works for you.  Note that it is possible to have a file name containing a period that the Finder does _not_ see as having an extension (for example, a file downloaded or changed to have a name such as "latest.map.updated").  Not very likely, but in this case neither are issues with using the Finder.